# Is there a way to add a timeout to a system call in a thread?

Tags: python, timeout, signals

My use case: I want to call `fcntl.flock()` on a file but have a timeout. Following the recipe in [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call/494273#494273), I wrapped my code in a `contextmanager` that implements timeouts via a Unix signal:

```
@contextmanager
def doTimeout(seconds):
    """Creates a "with" context that times out after the
    specified time."""
    def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
        pass

    original_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

    try:
        signal.alarm(seconds)
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, original_handler)
```

and used it as follows:

```
        with doTimeout(timeout):
            try:
                fcntl.flock(self.file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
                self.locked = True
                return True
            except (OSError, IOError) as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                    return False
                raise
```

This all worked perfectly, but unfortunately I can only do this from the main thread because only the main thread can catch signals. Is there a way to do it from another thread?

My alternatives at this point are to periodically test the lock and then sleep, or launch a subprocess. Neither of these is ideal; is there a better way?

Comment: Why [reinvent the wheel](https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: This particular wheel only works on the main thread. I'm hoping to set a timeout in another thread.

Comment: The filelock library that I linked to implements a timeout that works in threads.  The implication of the question was meant to be, why write your own implementation when this one already exists that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Ooops, didn't realize you'd made a link. Let me follow it.

Comment: OK, found the source code at https://github.com/tox-dev/py-filelock. It uses a polling/sleep loop, which is what I was doing. I guess that's the best approach then.

Comment: @dskrypa make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filelock](https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to accomplish exactly what you are looking for.  It supports a `timeout` argument to handle specifying a timeout before giving up on acquiring the lock.

Additionally, it handles cross-process locking in an OS-independent manner, using the `with lock:` syntax that should be familiar from stdlib multithreading / multiprocessing locks.

On Linux systems, it uses `fcntl.flock()`.